# Capistrano deploy of Rails app failing and saying there are missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, digital-ocean

I am using a digital ocean server to which I had already deployed successfully a few times. Suddenly, whenever I run `cap production deploy` it fails and tells me there are missing gems, some of which are in the development group so they shouldn't even be in production. Here is my console output with the missing gems. There are also some failed processes that seem to be related to the assets precompile.

```
DEBUG [c182dc11] Running [ -L /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/public/assets ] on 162.243.135.130
DEBUG [c182dc11] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/public/assets ]
DEBUG [c182dc11] Finished in 0.062 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [5bd74104] Running [ -d /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/public/assets ] on 162.243.135.130
DEBUG [5bd74104] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/public/assets ]
DEBUG [5bd74104] Finished in 0.064 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [92c16c38] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/public/assets on 162.243.135.130
DEBUG [92c16c38] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/public/assets
INFO [92c16c38] Finished in 0.061 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [7012f1eb] Running if test ! -d /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.135.130
DEBUG [7012f1eb] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [7012f1eb] Finished in 0.065 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [d02096e8] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check --path /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/bundle on 162.243.135.130


DEBUG [d02096e8] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check --path /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/bundle
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[32mRVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/Gemfile'.
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31mThe following gems are missingESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * nokogiri (1.6.8.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * globalid (0.3.7)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * net-ssh (3.2.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * net-scp (1.2.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * sshkit (1.11.3)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * airbrussh (1.1.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * debug_inspector (0.0.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * binding_of_caller (0.7.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * capistrano-harrow (0.5.3)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * capistrano (3.6.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * capistrano-rails (1.1.8)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * capistrano-sidekiq (0.5.4)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * capistrano3-puma (1.2.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * coderay (1.1.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * database_cleaner (1.5.3)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * responders (2.3.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * diff-lcs (1.2.5)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * docile (1.1.5)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * factory_girl (4.7.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * factory_girl_rails (4.7.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * jbuilder (2.6.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * jquery-rails (4.2.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * turbolinks (5.0.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * materialize-sass (0.97.7)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * method_source (0.8.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * slop (3.6.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * pry (0.10.4)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * sprockets (3.7.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * sprockets-rails (3.2.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * react-rails (1.9.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * rspec-support (3.5.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * rspec-core (3.5.4)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * rspec-expectations (3.5.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * rspec-mocks (3.5.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * rspec-rails (3.5.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * sass-rails (5.0.6)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * sdoc (0.4.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * simplecov-html (0.10.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * simplecov (0.11.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * spring (2.0.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * sprockets-es6 (0.9.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * uglifier (3.0.2)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[31m * web-console (2.3.0)ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8]       ESC[33mInstall missing gems with `bundle install`ESC[0m
 DEBUG [d02096e8]
 DEBUG [d02096e8] Finished in 1.037 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [62fad7fd] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on 162.243.135.130
 DEBUG [62fad7fd] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]       ESC[32mRVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]       you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/releases/20161105191648/Gemfile'.
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]       To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]       ESC[0m
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]
 DEBUG [62fad7fd]       bash: line 1:  7571 Killed                  ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

Here is my Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

And my deploy.rb file:

```
server '162.243.135.130', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@github.com:mghadley/team_hadley.git'
set :application,     'team_hadley'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

And, lastly, my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' 
gem 'materialize-sass', '~> 0.97.6'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.1.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem "sprockets"
gem "sprockets-es6"
gem "react-rails"
gem "cloudinary"
gem "jquery-slick-rails"
gem "sidekiq"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5.3'
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.11.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'

  gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', require: false
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end

group :produection do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'puma'
end
```

Does anyone happen to know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing output from `bundle check` that gems are missing. This is expected because capistrano-bundler first runs `bundle check` before running `bundle install`. You can disregard the `check` output.

The real problem is the last line of your log, which says:

```
bash: line 1:  7571 Killed                  ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/team_hadley/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

As you can see, `bundle install` is failing due to be killed by the operating system. This is almost certainly because you have exhausted the RAM and the OS is forced to stop the process.

As a solution, you can either add swap to your VM or upgrade to a VM with more RAM.

To be sure, check the logs in `/var/log/syslog` and look for memory-related errors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Comment: One follow up question if you don't mind - is running out of memory a common problem or should I take this as a sign that something else is wrong?

Comment: I can confirm that adding swap memory worked in my case where I was seeing similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, having the same issue, but not because of lack of memory: in my case, I didn't have yarn installed and got an "Missing gems" error while assets:precompile execution. If you're using yarn in your project, try:

1. curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
2. echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
3. sudo apt update
4. sudo apt install yarn

And try to deploy again